# Mail configuraion in jenkins for multiple mail id

Tags: jenkins

not able to add multiple mail id;s in reply list while configuring e-mail for jenkins.
1.tried comma seperation, 
2.also comma seperation with one space.

but issue not resolved.
please help

Thanks,
Sreedevi

Comment: show us your code

Comment: Thanks, but it resolved by filling recipient field by comma followed by a space. Earlier I was trying to fill " reply to" field